# How to define type for object with dynamic properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object which has `title` as string and `order` as number, and then there will be dynamic number of properties of type number on it

So I tried to define it like below

```
appraisalGroups: Array<{
    title: string,
    order: number,
    [key:string]: number,
}>;
```

and later this will be assigned like this (this is just an example in my read application there will be a loop and keys are coming from a rest api)

```
this.appraisalGroups[0]['mykey1'] = 5
```

and I got ts error

> Property 'title' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'number'

My question is how can I make it typed?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzdwmn

Comment: I'm not sure the solution, but the problem seems to be that you are mixing known property names with dynamic property names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this because index signatures force all properties to match their return type.  As stated in Typescript docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the dictionary pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type.

An index signature is explicitly saying "whenever this object is indexed with a value of this type, it will return a value of that type".

In your example, your index signature says that "whenever this object is indexed with a string, it will return a number". However, the compiler sees that this rule can be broken because one of your properties is not a number, so it throws an error.

I'm not sure what your problem space is but if the dynamic properties all have something in common, then it might be easier to create an interface to abstract their commonalities away.  How you use said interface really depends on what you want to do though.

EDIT:  You could also be cheeky and take a shortcut and simply use a Union type.  So instead of `[key:string]: number` you do `[key:string]: number | string`.

Comment: Just an FYI you can get around the enforcement by using an intersection type `{
    title: string,
    order: number} & {
    [key:string]: number
}` but such objects are only createable using `Object.assign `

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir ah yes an Intersection type is also possible.  Though I would say using the union type more accurately reflects the state of the property being a string or a number, as opposed to an entity that has both properties.  I did not know about the Object.assign requirement though, could you put me in the direction of where you read that?  Thanks.

Comment: @Willwsharp also I found out another similar solution is using `[key:string]:any`

Comment: @RezaRahmati yes that is possible, but it's best not to use `any` unless you really have to.  A Union type is superior in this situation assuming the result will either be a string or a number.