# Typescript create key using a generic type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a generic interface which accepts two types, something returned by `Entry, T` and the `key, K` which contains this.

I am not sure if this is something that can be done using typescript.

Does anyone know? Thanks!

```
// this is a bad way of doing it
export interface Reconfigure<T> {
  title: string
  keyOne?: Entry<T>[]
  keyTwo?: Entry<T>[]
  keyThree?: Entry<T>[]
  keyFour?: Entry<T>[]
}

// this is close to what I'd want to do, but doesn't work
export interface Reconfigure<T, K> {
  title: string
  [K]: Entry<T>[]
}
```

Comment: You can do what you want with a type alias e.g. `type Reconfigure<T, K> = { [key in K]: Entry<T> }` but not sure if you can get it working as nicely as an interface.

Comment: As an aside, when you add the phrase "doesn't work" in a question, you should always show the not-working outcome (i.e. the error/warning that it causes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TS(2352) Declare object with dynamic properties and one property with specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349619/ts2352-declare-object-with-dynamic-properties-and-one-property-with-specific-t)

Comment: @spender I'm not sure about that. OP wants that eventually, K will be a specific property (for ex. for K = 'foo', the interface will has the prop `foo: Entry<T>[]}`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type. The predefined types `Record` and `Partial` should let you to create a type based on a union of string literal types. Adding the fixed part of the type is just a matter of using an intersection type (`&`):

```
export type Reconfigure<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Partial<Record<K, Entry<T>>> &  {
    title : string
}

type T = Reconfigure<string, "k1" | "k2" | "k4">
// same as
// type T = {
//     k1?: Entry<string> | undefined;
//     k2?: Entry<string> | undefined;
//     k4?: Entry<string> | undefined;
//     title: string;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=5&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLigTwDwBUB8yA3sgG5wA2ArhAFzK4C+AsAFBsQAeADgPZRhkYTNxQAlCAl4gYwAOZUoEPABpkAaWRdIIACYBnZAAUovUQMzqImQgF5jcAcErYJUqLuzq16MFjz4gcgAZMjEbGFhYMBgFCj0+n6gcmws7KzCogzI9m7SsgpK2IlQyWoARADWAIzlyAA+yFUATHWNVQAs5fhsAPS9yPpwALYocPp9A5kouDnhrP2RYTUA-PS+-iXJhI1UehCyIBC6ANyTS8iVzWtoGDhbIHI7yHu6B6DHZwsDS5UdNxt7klHs9Xu8jqdzktorE6INgXIvotGEA)

Comment: This works for me and is pretty clean, thanks Titian!