# Equivalent types but unassignable when using optional index signature : why?

Tags: typescript

I have the following situation :

```js
type FilterQuery<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] } & RootQuerySelector<T>;

type RootQuerySelector<T> = {
  $and?: Array<FilterQuery<T>>;
}

class A<T> {
    queries: Array<FilterQuery<T>>

    constructor() {
        this.queries = []
    }

    stuff() {
        const query: FilterQuery<T> = { $and: this.queries }
        console.log(query)
    }
}
```

The `query` assignment in `stuff()` is marked by TS as an error :

```
const query: FilterQuery<T>
  Type '{ $and: FilterQuery<T>[]; }' is not assignable to type 'FilterQuery<T>'.
    Type '{ $and: FilterQuery<T>[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | undefined; }'.(2322)
```

**[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgRQK6pAHgCoB8UAvFAN5QDaAClHAHZQDWEIA9gGZR4C6A-AC5uNHlAC%20UAGRQASmzbBM2AMoQEEAMbA2KfAQDcAKEOhIs%20YqwoQq9Vp16S5Q1CgASAIb0AJoKgBBFBQPXHgkVCVrPQNDMWMNBA8AZySAxzIXVygARys4CCShQODQxGR0K1xCAmMsqA02eiTgFAx7FAAKAEpnOrrgAAs4JIA6XNR81NJKHkzXOLmoZowODm7evtcGpuAcyqEw8siqolIKTx8hQeGxvIK4za3GpLZ1EYQ2AHMO8esuxbicSAA)**

I was expecting `{ $and: this.queries }` to be a valid `FilterQuery` since it's a shape allowed by `RootQuerySelector` (Btw these types are from the MongoDB official node driver).

Why is there an issue here and how could I solve it ? Thank you.

Comment: I butted into [this kind of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56350585/14357) before. Armed with this knowledge, you can spead two values into a resulting object without error. [See here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgRQK6pAHgCoB8UAvFAEoD2Fwm2AyhAhAMbAUr5EBkUACgIYpgcfgk4BuAFCTQkclRpYUIBk1btOJKAG9JUfVAAk-AHYATAPwAuKAEEUKfrnhJUtZZwJSAvtOYJ+AGdAu01dAygARyU4CECbe0dnRGR0JVxCAmkI5goTQOAUDHUUAAoASh09CINgAAs4QIA6aNRYkNIAbQBdav1fPqgCjAAzEYqqmoNc-OAoMGAbASERMUItbW8pKf0ZgqgUSPj5ancVRhY2DnXSbSNTMxt6xpaYuKhfHag9udblGxcqTOmluUCa4IWABoweDDiFPjs9hQmE0EBQAOalP4gcqDXy+IA)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `{ [P in keyof T]?: T[P] }` is `Partial<T>` right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. And spreading works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug. The compiler has issues evaluating your object because there is no type information yet. He doesn't know what `{ [P in keyof T]?: T[P] }` resolves to before setting a real type for `T`. If you took `{ [P in keyof T]?: T[P] }` away, he wouldn't complain. But you can trick the compiler ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgRQK6pAHgCoB8UAvFAN5QDaAClHAHZQDWEIA9gGZR4C6A-AC5uNHlAC%20UAGRQASmzbBM2AMoQEEAMbA2KfAQDcAKEOhIs%20YqwoQq9Vp16S5Q1CgASAIb0AJoKgBBFBQPXHgkVCVrPQNDMWMNBA8AZySAxzIXVygARys4CCShQODQxGR0K1xCAmMsqA02eiTgFAx7FAAKAEpnOrrgAAs4JIA6XNR81NJKHkzXOLmoZowODm7evtcGpuAcyqEw8siqolIyMSNN13HrEc8fJ0HhsbyCy6vtpLZ1EYQ2AHMOjcQF1FnE4kA)):

```
class A<T> {
    queries: Array<FilterQuery<T>>

    constructor() {
        this.queries = []
    }

    stuff() {
        const query: FilterQuery<T> = {};
        query.$and = this.queries;
        console.log(query)
    }
}
```